# Passing OpenCV coordinates to OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, opencv

I have written two sets of code. One is  using OpenCV (for marker detection) and another OpenGL (for creating a simple 3D box).

But I have no clue how to integrate those two. For example: Displaying the box on detected maker.

With the functions of OpenCV such as `cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2`,`cvRodrigues2` I have obtained the rotation vector and rotation matrix. But I cannot understand how I can pass these points to OpenGL so that it can draw a 3d shape on the detected marker?

Answer (score 1):

You might try something [along these lines](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/11/10/20-lines-ar-in-opencv-wcode/).

They even have a [SVN repo](http://code.google.com/p/morethantechnical/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FOpenCVAR).